# "Stack" or "Add" MySQL results... or something

Tags: php, mysql

*Let me get right to it.
I have a MySQL table with a row that has text. Example...
    Entry | Tags
    post1 | tags, tag1, tag4
    post2 | tag1, tag2, tag4
I want to grab all the tags and display the tag and number of times it was used. Example...
    tags (1)
    tag1 (2)
    tag4 (2)
    tag2 (1)
Am I able to do this with my current setup? Thank you for your time.*

I went and built a new table called "tags". This is what it looks like...

```
ID | POSTID | TAG
1       1     tag1
2       1     tag2
3       2     tag5
4       3     tag2
5       3     tag2
```

Now, how can I go about building a list that would loo like this?

```
tag1 (1)
tag2 (3)
tag5 (1)
```

Comment: You should [***normalize***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table, by storing tags in a new table `tags` instead, this will be easier.

Comment: comma seperated list.... hmmm my best wishes on your journey. :)

Comment: If tags are unknown, I think this could not be resolved without stored procedures. Use correct structure for relation DB (like @MahmoudGamal said)

Comment: Definitely normalize your table. Separate Tag table has some advantages. Your current setup requires parsing all entries or some stored procedures that do the parsing.

Comment: This is still not a good database schema. Please refer to my message below. But if you want to keep this schema, you can do this: SELECT tag, COUNT(id) FROM tags GROUP BY tag

Comment: I already made the new table and made the changes to my script. I chose Matt's answer because, well, he answered the initial question. Now, I just need to make the same thing work with the new setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it, but it would be easiest to parse the tags in PHP, so for all tags:

```
$tagcount = array();
$query = "SELECT tags from table";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tags = explode(',', $row['tags']);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag = trim($tag);
        if (array_key_exists($tag, $tagcount)) {
            $tagcount[$tag]++;
        } else {
            $tagcount[$tag] = 1;
        }
    }
}
foreach ($tagcount as $key=>$value) {
     echo "<p>$key used $value time(s)";
}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: As others have said it would be more efficient/easier in the long run to use a separate tags table.

Comment: It will work, but you should definitly consider changing your database schema instead. This code will be very time consuming if you have a lot of data.

Comment: I agree, have added note at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this:

Entry table:

```
id (auto-increment, primary) | EntryName
0                              Entry1
1                              Entry2
```

Tags table:

```
id (auto-increment, primary) | TagName
0                              Tag1
1                              Tag2
```

EntryHasTag table:

```
id_entry | id_tag
0          1
0          2
1          1
1          2
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.id_tag) FROM EntryHasTag e LEFT JOIN Tags t ON e.d_tag = t.id GROUP BY e.id_tag
```